# Rails: How do I get reference from one .yml files to second .yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have 2 models User and Account and I want to create a seed data in by using .yml file

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one: account
end
```

and account.rb

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: user
end
```

my .yml files are

```
config/users.yml

user1: 
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Doe'
user2: 
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Wick'

and config/accounts.rb

account1:
  balance: 1000
  slug: 'saving'
account2: 
  balance: 500
  slug: 'marketing'
```

so my question here is that how can i add user1 to account1 and user2 to account2 and so on.
and how can i use it in seed file the create some data.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you try to handle your users and accounts in yaml files? Why not store it in the database? Or do you want to use these data as fixtures or seeds? You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails-3`, are you really still using version 3 of Rails that is about 7 years old?

Comment: @spickermann I want to use it in seeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution
first you have to add reference of account slug in users.yml like this as per our account slug

```
user1: 
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Doe'
  account_slug: 'saving'
user2: 
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Wick'
  account_slug: 'marketing'
```

so now in my seed file I will compare user's account_slug with account.yml's slug attribute.

```
user_seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'users.yml')
user_config = YAML::load_file(user_seed_file)

account_seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'accounts.yml')
account_config = YAML::load_file(account_seed_file)

user_config.each do |user_key, user_value|
  user = User.find_or_create_by(user_value.except("account_slug"))
  account_config.each do |account_key, account_value|
    account = user.account.present? ? user.account : user.create_account(account_value) if account_value["slug"] == user_value["product_slug"]
  end
end
```

It will do exact what we need

here in the code this line

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(user_value.except("account_slug"))
```

takes all attributes from users.yml file except account_slug because it is a extra attribute.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way for seed data would be to create a Ruby file in `db/seeds.rb` that looks like this:

```
user1 = User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe')
user2 = User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Wick')

Account.create(user: user1, balance: 1000)
Account.create(user: user2, balance: 500)
```

And to run it with `rails db:seed`

See the [Rails Guides about seed data](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)